# Should I use Serializable for my DTO and why should I use?

Tags: java, spring, api, serialization, serializable

As far as I know, Serializable should be used when deserialization is needed e.g. using dto as return object in APIs. But should I use Serializable for the whole DTO objects or just for the general one?

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GaDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -xxxx;

    private String id;
    private GaStatus gaStatus;
    private PlaTurn plaTurn;
    private PlaDTO pla1;
    private PlaDTO pla2;

}
```

This DTO is the return type of `ResponseEntity` but there are other DTOs that this GaDTO uses.

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PlaDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -yyyyyy;

    private List<PiDTO> pis;

    private PiDTO mainPi;

}

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PiDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -zzzzzz;

    private Integer stos;

}
```

Should I only use Serializable for GaDTO or do other DTOs need it too?
And why should I use it?

Comment: This depends on which library you are using to do serialization. If you're just serializing to JSON using Jackson, Gson or something similar, you don't need to add that interface.

Comment: Yeah, I just serialize to JSON using Jackson. If I remove the interface, everything works well. This means I don't need it?

Comment: Yes, it is unrelated to Jackson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to implement Serializable and Deserializable for your DTO because it is already handled by Spring Boot Jackson Package.